# Ordering array of objects alphabetically by name, data fetched from API

Tags: reactjs, api, sorting, object, arraylist

I am fetching data(a contact list: name, email, phone, etc)from API. The mapping is done and I can see the list of names displayed but now I want them in alphabetical order from a-z.

I am trying this but i get "Unhandled Rejection(typeError): a.name.localCompare is not a function).

How can I solve it?

```
const UserList = () => {
 
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState()
  const [showUser, setShowUser] = useState(true)
 
  
  const onHandleClick = () => setShowUser(false)
 const DisplayUser =(user) => {
    setSelectedUser(user);
    setShowUser(true);
  }
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch(URL)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => setUsers(json));
      }, [])
    
      return (
        <>
          <Header>      
            <h1>Contact list</h1>
          </Header>
          <Container> 
              <div>
              {users.sort((a,b) => a.name.localCompare(b.name))
              .map(user => (
                <div key={user.id}>
                  <User onClick ={() => DisplayUser(user)}>{user.name}</User>
                </div>
              ))}         
              </div>
```

My data:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo it's localeCompare() method, not localCompare